# How can switch between two Layouts in only one Activity android

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

I'm new to Android, Developing an application to give users the ability to publish posts with images and small texts, I'm looking for a way to give the possibility to the user to edit his post like the screenshot; so when the user press the edit button The layout changes and the menu on the top changes as well, for example instead of the TextView I will show an EditText, so the user can change his text.

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html), to switch between two layouts xmls. Define

```
<ViewFlipper>
  <include layout="@layout/xml1" />
  <include layout="@layout/xml2" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

then you can use viewFlipper.showNext() and viewFlipper.showPrevious() to toggle between the two views. By default, the first xml layout will be rendered.

Fragments can also be used in this case, but I don't see the need for having individual lifecycles for the two layouts.  ViewFlipper is a normal viewgroup which can be added even in listviews easily, not that easy with fragments.

Hope that helps.

Comment: And how to use ViewFlipper in the XML file ?

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/viewflipper/android-viewflipper-example/